# Проблемы с версткой в браузере Mozilla

Tags: joomla, html, вёрстка

Есть сайт, сделанный на Joomla 3.15. Когда я открываю его в браузере Google Chrome (последней версии) и браузере Internet Explorer 11 - все отлично, скриншот ниже:
[image: В Google Chrome и IE 11 все хорошо]

А вот в браузере Mozilla Firefox 32.0 все плохо:
[image: В Mozilla Firefox 32.0 все плохо]

Почему так происходит? Как это можно исправить?

У картинки стоят такие css свойства:

```
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Comment: @Deonis, спасибо помогло! Можете оформить как ответ?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы задалие картинке значение display: block;, то скорее всего, что на неё влияет чей-то float. Добавьте изображению:

```
clear: both;
```